# Passwordless SSH Solaris->RHEL without ever prompting for password

Tags: ssh, redhat, solaris

I need make a script to SSH from a Solaris machine (A) to an RHEL machine (B) (actually it's Oracle Linux).

Is it necessary to enter B's password at some point?

I want to automate the process with a script and I was wondering if I could avoid any inputs.

Unfortunately "expect" isn't an option.

Comment: What's the use case?  Does it have to be ssh, or could you run a custom cgi script accessible via HTTPS using curl or wget?

Comment: Yes I am afraid it has to be ssh - it's really restrictive as I am just adding some lines in a legacy script. The Solaris machine is going to create a new key every time I run the test. The RHEL machine though is going to be static, which means that I am able to do whatever I want beforehand and it;s going to stay this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this in two ways:

- a) create an SSH key without passphrase, and deploy the public key to B
- b) create an SSH key with passphrase, load it once into ssh-agent on boot and make the connection to B use this agent. This is more secure than the first option.

Links:

- a) http://hortonworks.com/kb/generating-ssh-keys-for-passwordless-login/
- b) http://rabexc.org/posts/using-ssh-agent

Comment: Thanks. But that still prompts for a password the first time, right? I am looking for a way to never give input from the keyboard. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh i didn't read your comment about Solaris going to create a new key every time. You need to get the key you'll be using onto the Redhat machine somehow (but you can do it with another use or another protocol), or you need to use the same key every time.

Comment: I copy Solaris' key to RHEL using rcp (append it to authorized_keys) and it works fine, but I do still have to give a password the first time I attempt to connect. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you generated the key without password, yes it sounds like something is wrong. Could be the permissions, the .ssh folder needs to be 700 and authorized_keys 644.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a single-sign-on (SSO) setup.  I have not personally done an ssh SSO configuration, but I found a few links that look decent: [Red Hat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/sso-ov.html), [an RHEL blog post](http://www.dalemacartney.com/2013/08/30/single-sign-on-sso-with-secure-shell-ssh/), and [one from another Linux distribution](https://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Passwordless_SSH_with_Single_Signon) (this last one is the most step-by-step of the three).  Hope one of those helps!